# $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty , 0} \left(\frac{\sum_1^n i^r/ n}{\sum_1^{n+1} i^r/(n+1)}\right)^{1/r} $?

Tags: analysis

**Edited**

please help me!
 how can I evaluate:
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\sum_1^n i^r/ n}{\sum_1^{n+1} i^r/(n+1)}\right)^{1/r}$$ and

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\sum_1^n i^r/ n}{\sum_1^{n+1} i^r/(n+1)}\right)^{1/r}$$

Comment: What does $r \to \infty , 0$ mean? Are we evaluating two problems here? One when $r \to \infty$ and the other when $r \to 0$?

Comment: yes, it is two problems. one for $r\rightarrow \infty $ and the other for $r\rightarrow 0$

Comment: limits are evaluated not solved

Answer (score 0):

I'll solve the 0 case.
 $$\lim_{r\to 0}\left(\dfrac{(n+1)(\sum_1^ni^r)}{n\sum_1^{n+1}i^r}\right)^{\frac 1 r}=\lim_{r\to 0} \left(\dfrac{1 +r\dfrac{\log n!}{n}}{1 +r\dfrac{\log n+1!}{n+1}}\right)^{\frac 1r}=\exp\left({\dfrac{\log n!}{n}-\dfrac{\log (n+1)!}{n+1}}\right)$$ This is all by taking a $1^{st}$ order approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Focus on the expression $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i^r\right)^{1/r}$.

For $r$ large, note $n^{r-1}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i^r\leq n^r$.

For $r$ small, try taking logs and applying l'Hospital's rule.